# Upgraded emacs to 28.2, flycheck fails: undefined elisp macros

Tags: emacs, flycheck, melpa

I just upgraded to emacs 28.2 and my flycheck stopped working. When it loaded it got an error

`File mode specification error: (void-function -doto)`

I found **-doto** in elpa/dash, which was installed when flycheck was upgraded. It does not get loaded automatically, and when I load it manually and try using flycheck there is a similar error

`while loading: (void-function -compose)`

This one I can't find, it does not seem to be anywhere on my system.

The emacs is a new install, packages were all installed with melpa
I've reloaded flycheck (version 32) from melpa-stable. **-compose** is used in a few of the files in lhp-mode, which was also just installed.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Perhaps a newer flycheck from the non-stable melpa has a fix.  The melpa-stable release might not be as up to date as you expect.  https://github.com/flycheck/flycheck/tags says it's a year old.

Comment: did you install the packages fresh after the upgrade? I think I've had similar problems when there were multiple versions of the same package installed

Comment: @Rorschach yes, I did the upgrade after it failed. The previous version had been manually loaded a long time ago, I deleted it and used melpa. I may just give up on flycheck, it's nice to have but maybe not worth investigating this problem.

Comment: Is you `dash` version 2.19.1?  Cause it looks like `-compose` was moved into dash a couple years ago - [commit](https://github.com/magnars/dash.el/commit/5eea1560c785d3873316b42dce480fdfefbb7d04)

Comment: when I do an upgrade I delete the whole elpa (`user-package-dir`) directory and reinstall just to be sure

Comment: Full points to @Rorschach, I had an old version of dash lying around that took precedence. I deleted it and everything worked. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Solved by Rorschach in a comment, it was a version issue. After deleting an old version of dash.el in my load path it worked.